# iText 5.5.13 - Not able to add space at top of page

Tags: java, itext

I am migrating PDF support code originally using iText version 2.0.7 to 5.5.13.  I am having trouble positioning my page content in the correct place on the page.

Here's a piece of code (works as expected, originally) that we used to provide spacing within a page:

```
    protected Element createTopPadding(int size) {
        PdfPTable padding = new PdfPTable(1);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
        
        cell.setPaddingTop(size);
        cell.setBorderWidth(0);
        
        padding.addCell(cell);
        
        return padding;
    }
```

Basically, just adding an element (with settable PaddingTop) at a point within the page.  The element created and returned by the above code is added (document.add()) to the document that's being built.

I am able to generate the document (the PDF), but I am missing the required spacing and this causes text to overlap.

I've tried several things... setPaddingTop() on the table object (not just the cell object), setLeading() on the cell object, I also tried setUseAscender(and Descender) to 'true'.  All to no avail.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

After some additional work, I have come up with this solution.  If there's a better way, I would be happy to learn that as well.

Basically, I just added content (a Phrase) to the cell before adding the cell to the table.  Here's a look:

```
    protected Element createTopPadding(int size) {
    
    PdfPTable padding = new PdfPTable(1);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    
    cell.setPhrase(new Phrase(" ", FontFactory.getFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, TEXT_FONT, Font.NORMAL)));
    cell.setPaddingTop( size );
    cell.setBorderWidth( 0 );
    
    padding.addCell(cell);
    
    return padding;
}
```